# Use wildcard with variable on autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, wildcard

Im working with a data sheet of 25,000+rows of data. i need to apply a formula to each row of data, but i want to narrow it down with filters before applying the formula so im not wasting time waiting for it to loop through 25,000+ rows of data.

I have a variable string of text that takes the first two words of the full string, and i want to filter using that string with a wildcard (*), below is what i have, however it gives me an error with the wildcard, is there another way to accomplish this, or do i have something wrong? thank you.

```
dim find as integer
dim fnm as string

find = Application.WorksheetFunction.find(" ", isearch.fundnmbox.Value, 3)
fnm = Left(isearch.fundnmbox.Value, find)

rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
'fnm is the variable string
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$P").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="&fnm&"*", Operator:=xlAnd

'(theres more to the code, just providing what is relevant)
```

Comment: with spaces around the & it should be fine. & fnm & "*"

Comment: well im dummy, i should have thought of that... thanks @warcupine